# How to pass multiple text in the same timestamp to keras embedding layer

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a text dataset with 50 timestamps and each time stamp contains 2-3 texts. I want to pass this data to LSTM for sequence modelling. I want to use keras embedding layer for this purpose. I am also using pretrained word vectors which will be passed to embedding layer. Is there a way to pass multiple text at the same time stamp in embedding layer?